# button labeled based on ajax call; on click, button text to add to input box

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 15 buttons and it is randomly labeled using data from ajax. What I need next is when I click on these buttons, it will append the button text (only 1 letter) to whatever is in its corresponding input box. Each button and input has a unique ID based on the row it is in; each row has 15 buttons.

HTML code for row 1 buttons (I have numerous rows). The buttons are not button'd via jQuery UI.

```
<table width="180" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><button id="R1L1butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L2butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L3butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L4butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L5butt" class="letters"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="R1L6butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L7butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L8butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L9butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L10butt" class="letters"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="R1L11butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L12butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L13butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L14butt" class="letters"></button></td>
    <td><button id="R1L15butt" class="letters"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's my latest code:

```
//This is part of ajax success
//letArr is an array where the data from ajax is stored
//row2 is also from ajax
//ranArr is an array that contains the numbers 1-15
//letterArr is an array that contains the letters from A-Z
//This part works (except for the bindbuttons function)

for (var z=0; z<letArr.length; z++) //label random buttons depending on the data from ajax 
{
  ran1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*ranArr.length);
  $("#R" + row2 + "L" + ranArr[ran1] + "butt").text(letArr[z]);
  bindbuttons(row2, ranArr[ran1], letArr[z]);
  ranArr.splice(ran1, 1);
}

for (var a=0; a<(15-letArr.length); a++) //fill in the other buttons with random letters
{
  ran1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*ranArr.length);
  ran2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*letterArr.length);
  $("#R" + row2 + "L" + ranArr[ran1] + "butt").text(letterArr[ran2]);
  bindbuttons(row2, ranArr[ran1], letterArr[ran2]);
  ranArr.splice(ran1, 1);
}
```

Then this is the bind function:

```
function bindbuttons(c, d, e)
{
  $("#R" + c + "L" + d + "butt").on("click", function() {
    $("#R" + c + "anstext").val( function (i, v) {
      return v + e;
    });
  });
}
```

I have tried the following:
1. I tried switching between .text() and .html() to label the buttons. Both work good.
2. Within ajax success, using .on (to bind directly within) and $(this).text but console.log is not even showing any text.
3. Still within ajax success, using the value straight from the array (letArr[z]) and (letterArr[ran2]) but both not showing in console.log too past that .text(letArr[z]) and .text(letterArr[ran2])
4. Finally, putting it in a function to be called within ajax success and passing parameters but that doesn't work as well.

I am not sure how to go about what I want to happen and I'm just trying combinations to see what will work. Can someone point me in the right direction? Basically what I want is, when the button is clicked, whatever the label/text of the button is, it is to be added to whatever is in the input field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I can't imagine what this is for and it kinda makes me curious.

I'm also not clear on where the failures are in the code you presented.

What I would recommend is using input type="button" rather than buttons...this way you can easily grab the value....then make sure they all elements are getting assigned values properly (you can check in your browsers web developers tools / firebug)....then get something like this working (not 100% sure the best way to get the value...you might need to get it via an ID)

```
function bindbuttons(c, d, e)
{
  $("#R" + c + "L" + d + "butt").on("click", function() {
    alert(this.value);
  });
}
```

then move on to inserting it into the input (which should be easy something like...)

```
$("#R" + c + "anstext").val(this.value);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. :D It's for a game, similar with "Pictowords" or "4 pictures in 1." All related information are in a table, as well as the answers separated by letter (1 column, 1 letter). That's why I need it to populate the buttons by the letter I get from my table then put random letters on the rest of the buttons. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks again!